# Get all Mysql columns containing same other column

Tags: php, mysql

Hi lets say I have a table like this:

```
________________________________________________________
|
|    id     |     order    |  date   |  item  |   price|
-------------------------------------------------------
|     1            1st        date       i1       10,00|
|-------------------------------------------------------    
|     2            2nd       date        u2       15,00|
|-------------------------------------------------------
|     3            1st       date        i1       20,00|
|------------------------------------------------------- 
|     4            2nd       date        u2       30,00|
|-------------------------------------------------------
```

I need to get total sum  of items containing same order name and print DISTINCT orders like:

order_name - date - total sum.  or better way to create new tabel and store there total sum of each order and in this table add sum id in each row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will literally return `order_name - date - total sum`, assuming your `date` column is `date`

```
SELECT CONCAT(order, " - ", date, " - ", SUM(price)) as Result
FROM orders
GROUP BY `order`
```

To add a quantity, try this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(order, " - ", date, " - ", CASE WHEN quantity > 1 THEN (quantity * SUM(price)) ELSE SUM(price) END) as Result
FROM orders
GROUP BY `order`
```

Comment: working perfect. there is a way to multiply item if it has quantity?

Comment: Try the second block above. I haven't tried it, but it should work.

Comment: Great! now I'm having problem to print result in PHP should I use while or not? thank you

Comment: Yes, you can, but don't have to. But the value you are going to look for is `Result`. Example: `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query); echo $row['Result'];`

Comment: hmm strange, I'm getting `Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in...` I have this code:
 `$uzklausa = "SELECT CONCAT(order, " - ", date, " - ", SUM(price * quantity)) as Result`
FROM orders
GROUP BY `order`";
$uz = mysql_query($uzklausa);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($uz);
echo $row['Result'];`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13621/discussion-between-deividas-juskevicius-and-sixeightzero)

Answer (score 1):

Use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT SUM(`price`)
FROM `orders`
GROUP BY `order`
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html